# Algolia search from behind a firewall

Tags: algolia, docusaurus

I've seen a lot of conversation about offline search, but I'm not clear on something - Can I get search working from behind a firewall either by specifying a proxy or opening up a port? Is that something I can simply specify in the `algoliaOptions` field or would I need to create my own search bar as described here: [Custom Search Bar in Docusaurus 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501754/custom-search-bar-in-docusaurus-2).

We're trying to use Docusaurus internally, but we're stumbling over the SaaS aspect of it given that all of our content is internal and our company has strict access issues.

Thanks in advance! (and apologies if it's already been asked)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have better chances asking this on the Algolia project. This is not an issue specific to Docusaurus, which is merely a static site generator. Try posting on https://www.algolia.com/support/

Comment: Thanks! I've been in touch there as well.